# Magento 1.3.3 error at showing checkout shoppin cart

Tags: php, magento, methods, checkout

As soon as I try to add a product to the shopping cart in Magento, it spits this PHP error:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection::addTierPriceData()`

I don't know what is it about; I've tried the Magento forum and I haven't yet found out a solution to this.

I installed magento through SimpleScripts.com, in a hostmonster.com account.  My store is still waiting to launch due to this strange error(www.caninarua.com/shop).  I really don't know what to do now...please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any extensions or customizations to the shop installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing in the default v1.3.2.4 Magento codebase that calls `addTierPriceData()` on that class.  It does, however, exist in v1.4.2 and is called by `Mage_Bundle_Model_Product_Price::getFinalPrice()`

So, either you have a commercial theme that is calling that function (unlikely), or an extension that has been installed that is not compatible with v1.3.3

If you turn on logging in System>Config>Admin>Developer, you should get a full stack trace in `var\log\exception.log` which you can paste into your question and we can verify which piece of code is calling that method.